# Ionic 2 Cannot view span inside of ion-item, how to render simple text

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but when I try to add a span to a Ion Item the span is not rendered, nor div.

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-title>
  <div>
    <button ion-button (click)="toggleEdit()">Edit</button>
  </div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-item [hidden]="editOptions.!isEditing">
        <span class="inline-edit">Text</span>

        <ion-label color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input></ion-input>
        <span class="inline-edit">{{value}}&nbsp;</span>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item [hidden]="!editOptions.isEditing">
        <ion-label color="primary">{{label}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="value" [required]="required" [type]="type" [name]="value"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-list>
</ion-card>
```

Ion label and Input display and work fine, but how when I try to use a span or a div in an Item they aren't rendering.  Even when I inspect them in chrome.

How can I render simple text, Am I not allowed to use HTML in a component?  What Is the Ionic 2 equivently for rendering small amounts of text, it appears labels have to always be over an input, so what component should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of how content projection works, the `ion-item` will only render some components (like the `ion-label` and the `ion-input`) but will ignore some other html elements.

There may be other ways to fix it, but AFAIK you have two choices:

1) If the text is just a small text , you can use [notes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/note/Note/).

> A note is detailed item in an ion-item. It creates greyed out element
>   that can be on the left or right side of an item.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-note item-start>
        Left Note
      </ion-note>
      My Item
      <ion-note item-end>
        Right Note
      </ion-note>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

You can then play with the style rules to adapt it to your scenario.

2) Add the `item-start`, `item-end`, `item-left`, `item-right` or `item-content` attribute to the ignored html elements.

```
Attribute       Description
item-start      Placed to the left of all other elements, outside of the inner item.
item-end        Placed to the right of all other elements, inside of the inner item, outside of the input wrapper.
item-content    Placed to the right of any ion-label, inside of the input wrapper.
```

Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nNaQRm9iXFnB7O2IpHd3?p=preview) so you can play with those attributes until you get the desired layout.

```
  <ion-item style="background: transparent;">
      <span item-content class="inline-edit">Text</span>
      <ion-label color="primary">Label</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
      <span item-content class="inline-edit">Value</span>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: Weird thing happened, I came back to my project and now spans are working inside of the item, I didn't add any class to them but they started working today

Comment: really? oh... Are you sure ionic/the browser is not caching the view?

Comment: Yeah I'm really confused now I'll upload pictures when I get back to the project