# Display HTML dynamically from storage

Tags: html, ionic3, display

I work on a Ionic v3 app and I'm trying to display HTML in a *ngFor.

I've my TestPage.html with :

```
  <ion-list *ngFor="let c of cities">
        <ion-item>
                <div [innerHTML]="c.html_rate"></div>
         </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

In `c.html_rate` I've some `<ion-icon name="star-half"></ion-icon>`.

But on the screen nothing appear...

I've also try: `<div [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(c.html_rate)"></div>`

But that does not work...

Comment: Did you check, if there are any errors in browser console ?

Comment: Yes of course, and I have no error..

Answer (score 0):

As shown [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448237/ionic-2-cannot-view-span-inside-of-ion-item-how-to-render-simple-text) ion-item can only render particular elements. You are attempting to render an ion-icon within the ion-item component which doesn't work.

You can test this is true simply by replacing what is being injected into your div. If you swap `<ion-icon name="star-half"></ion-icon>` for `<ion-note>Testing</ion-note>`

Comment: I try and the HTML is not interpreted .